# What's wrong about my analysis?

Tags: matrices, determinant

When I read the [document](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html) about Harris corner detection, I got confused about the matrix $M=\sum_{x, y}w(x,y)\begin{bmatrix}I_xI_x & I_x I_y \\I_xI_y & I_yI_y\end{bmatrix}$

IMHO, $M$ is singular -- for $det(M)=I_xI_xI_yI_y - I_xI_yI_xI_y=0$.
So one of the Eigenvalue should be 0, which is definitely wrong according to the discussion in the link. Question is what's wrong here? I've been struggling with this for several hours, but still have no clue.

I'll be very grateful if someone could shed some light one it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the $I$ numbers or matrices? If the latter, then they may not commute.

Comment: $M$ is a sum of matrices each of which is singular, but that doesn't imply that $M$ is singular.

Comment: I see. Thank you! @QiaochuYuan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wiki page for [Corner detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection) refers to $M$ ($A$ on Wikipedia) as the *structure tensor*.  The sum over weights $w(x,y)$ means that the matrix $M$ can also be written as
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} \left< I_x^2 \right> && \left<I_x I_y\right> \\
 \left<I_x I_y\right> && \left<I_y^2\right>
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the form of $w$ depends on the type of averaging window.  Evidently, then, the determinant is not identically zero.

Comment: I'm sorry that I still don't understand yet. Could you explain it further? In my opinion $$det(M)=I_x^2I_y^2-(I_xI_y)^2$$ which is zero

Comment: You are ignoring the weighting.  The determinant is $\left<I_x^2\right>\left<I_y^2\right>-{\left<I_x I_y\right>}^2$ which is not zero in general.  Its not zero for the same reason $\int f^2 \int g^2 \neq \int fg \int fg$. The angle brackets denote the sum over the weight function $w$.